# How to incement row id with identity to off

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, rdbms

I am getting this error while i do select.

```
DECLARE @TopID INT
SELECT @TopID = MAX([QuestionId]) from [SurveyQuestions];

 SELECT
       @TopID = @TopID + 1   
       ,[questiontext]
      ,[DeptID]
      ,[SurveyID]   
  FROM [SOSS].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions] where surveyid =80
```

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.

I know there is a posibility to fix this error with identity set to ON.but i dont want that as my db is hosted in legecy application, changing this will make other things to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way you are selecting, you cant use operators in select with other columns being fetched. See this [link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-141.aspx) for some explanation on what you are doing wrong.

I think what you really require is this :

```
DECLARE @TopID INT
SELECT @TopID = MAX([QuestionId]) from [SurveyQuestions];

 SELECT
       @TopID + 1   
       ,[questiontext]
      ,[DeptID]
      ,[SurveyID]   
  FROM [SOSS].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions] where surveyid =80
```

**EDIT :** 
Or a `ROW_NUMBER` based solution like :

```
    DECLARE @TopID INT
    SELECT @TopID = MAX([QuestionId]) from [SurveyQuestions];

     SELECT
           @TopID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as TopID 
           ,[questiontext]
          ,[DeptID]
          ,[SurveyID]   
      FROM [SOSS].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions] where surveyid =80
```

Improving a bit on the Previous Answer (combined into one query):

```
 SELECT (
        SELECT TOP 1 QuestionId
        FROM SurveyQuestions
        ORDER BY QuestionId DESC
        ) 
+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (   ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS TopID
, [questiontext], [DeptID], [SurveyID]
FROM [SOSS].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions]
WHERE surveyid = 80
```

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe783/7/0)

Another Alternative, combing your 2 queries :

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ForgeRock) as MAx_Id
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as Row_ID, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ForgeRock ORDER BY Id DESC) +
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as New_Id,
    productName,
    description
FROM
    ForgeRock
```

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe783/8/0)

Comment: not incrimenting ..it just show same topid in all rows..i want to increment topid in each row

Comment: Still the same TOPID valriable has same value in all rows , i want to get it incremented

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the identity.  It has to do with the `select`.  You have:

```
  SELECT  @TopID = @TopID + 1, 
         [questiontext], [DeptID], [SurveyID]   
  FROM [SOSS].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions]
  WHERE surveyid = 80
```

This has an assignment *and* it returns values.  I think you really want:

```
  SELECT @TopId + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as rownum, 
         [questiontext], [DeptID], [SurveyID]   
  FROM [SOSS].[dbo].[SurveyQuestions]
  WHERE surveyid = 80;
```

Note:  If you actually want the results in a particular order, then add an `ORDER BY` *both* to the query and to the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: i want this row number to be incremented from the TopID that is max value of the id, now it is incremented from 1 which is not correct

Comment: @SmartestVEGA . . . Just add the offset onto the row number.